# When I convert date and time to only time, the cell becomes read only

Tags: c#, database, date

I would like to understand the concept behind this.

I am making a database in c#. Now, I wish to have only date instead of date and time.

So, I went for the following command in sql query pane:

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar, deal_start_date, 101) AS 'deal_start_date'
FROM client`

The desired result comes but the data becomes read only and hence cant be edited.

[image: The result is per this snap]

Further, it does not stay permanently. I mean,
On clicking `show table data` again the date-time format comes.

Can any one tell me why the cells become read-only and how to keep the changes permanently through UI only??

Many thanks.

Comment: did you refresh the table> try it.

Comment: yup...refreshing doesnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get a perfect answer but I found an alternative. I was trying with datetime datatype in MS SQL database. When I changed it to varchar(12), I got the desired result. i.e in date format.
(Thanks to insights provided by *Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen* )

This is actually improper to follow as with size 12 in varchar, the time part is truncated.
(If the size of varchar is increased, the time part will be present)
But It served my purpose.

But I am still waiting for a correct answer,if any.

Comment: I can ask again: Inside what type of GUI component are you trying to display (and edit) your date?

Comment: Its a webmethod I will be calling it in Android App.

Comment: Ok, then I have no clue how you can configure that component unfortunately (and I can't tell if it's possible)

Comment: Thats fine as I have found an alternative. But I will still wait for correct method. :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess on the read only part, is that since you are now converting the original value, you loose the link towards the column in the database. Just like a computed column can't be edited (how would you for example write to the column from the query that is defined as `A+B as 'C'`.

Inside what type of component are you showing this in your GUI? Maybe you can ahve your query remain as `SELECT deal_start_date FROM client`, and filter out the time part from your component?

Or, if you don't use the time in any other place in your application, change the column from `datetime` to `date` in the database.

Comment: the columns are NOT read only when simple show data is there(with both date and time format) So,probably ur assumption is right. +1 for that.  But keeping it readonly wont help me. So any alternative to that? Also, it does not even remain permanent

Comment: In c# based sql, only date datatype is not there. :(

Comment: But you are using a MS SQL database right? Have you tried changing the column type from Management Studio? Right click the table name and click Design. Have you researched into filtering what is actually shown on the component end, and not the database end? Inside what component in your GUI do you show the date?